# Changing values inside an MNIST tensor

Tags: python, deep-learning, pytorch, mnist

For experimental reasons, I am trying to change the values inside a tensor of size (64,1,28,28) which is a tensor containing the pixel values of 64 images from the MNIST dataset. I am trying to replace them all with ones.

However, I am trying to apply the `where` method of torch with no avail.

```
main = torch.randn(64, 1, 28, 28)
ones = torch.ones(64, 1, 28, 28)

torch.where(main < 0, ones, ones)
torch.where(main > 0, ones, ones)
```

Does the `where` method work only on lesser dimensions?
If so, how can this be done in a better way?

Comment: main = torch.where(main < 0, ones, ones);
main = torch.where(main > 0, ones, ones)     will change all of the values in main to 1. Strange way to do it, but if that is what you are wanting to do, what you have will work you just need to add main =

Comment: Awesome @KeithJohnson. You mention that it is a strange way to do it, is there any other faster or elegant way to do ?

Comment: . main[:, :, :, :] = 1  should work  and should also change values that are exactly 0 to 1